# Camel : How to use same header in file component

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have requirement where I need to read a message from a queue.
queue has body and header and this body and header I want to use in every file read of the next processor.

```
from("activemq:index.init")
    //.process(new PrintProcessor())
    .from("file:/home/arvind/Desktop/Camel/Index?noop=true&recursive=true").
```

location

> /home/arvind/Desktop/Camel/Index

I have lot of folder and files I want the header (came from activemq) while processing all file and folder.

I tried in print processor to header header from in.header and set in out.header but didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry can you try to explain this a bit better - its a bit unclear / confusing what you ask

Comment: When I am reading file, the header I got from activemq is venished, so I want to retain the header I got from activemq

Comment: @Claus Isben : I have added comments, is it clear now or still misleading ? could you plz help me

Comment: But wher in yhour .from(file...) do you use the headers?

Comment: I am seeing header in the commented line process(new PrintProcessor())  here I am printing headers